# How to specify that app must perform important tasks in the background?

Tags: iphone, ios, multitasking

I'm making an app that needs to run in the background. It plays online radio and at the same time must perform calculations.

I know there is a background expiration handler but it is very limited in time to my knowledge. Is there a way an app can perform calculations in the background for a very long time?

Someone mentioned something about specifying your app needs navigation and then it can keep doing important things. How?

Answer (score 0):

From the Apple documentation:
Implementing Long-Running Background Tasks

> For tasks that require more execution time to implement, you must
>   request specific permissions to run them in the background without
>   their being suspended. In iOS, only specific app types are allowed to
>   run in the background:
>
> Apps that play audible content to the user while in the background,
>   such as a music player app
>  Apps that keep users informed of their
>   location at all times, such as a navigation app
>  Apps that support
>   Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP) 
> Newsstand apps that need to
>   download and process new content 
> Apps that receive regular updates
>   from external accessories 
> Apps that implement these services must
>   declare the services they support and use system frameworks to
>   implement the relevant aspects of those services. Declaring the
>   services lets the system know which services you use, but in some
>   cases it is the system frameworks that actually prevent your
>   application from being suspended.

Your app seems to be ok for the

> Apps that play audible content to the user while in the
>   background,such as a music player app

While your app is playing music you can do the calculation you are mentioning. For more info check the Apple documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html)